# Extracting a Java record nested pattern of record graph where one of the components is null

Tags: java, pattern-matching, record, java-record

I am using a record pattern matching for a records graph. The record components are nicely extracted, so lots of accessors code can be omitted. I wonder how to solve gracefully the null checks. I noticed that they are done under the hood of pattern extracting mechanism (I have checked the decompiled pattern), but no message is given that one of the components is null.
For given code:

```
private void start() {
    LabeledPoint pointGamma = new LabeledPoint(null, "gamma");
    printExtractPoint(pointGamma);
    printIgnorePoint(pointGamma);
}

void printExtractPoint(LabeledPoint lp) {
    System.out.println("print extract point");
    if (lp instanceof LabeledPoint(Point(var x, var y), var label)) {
        System.out.println(" - point.label: " + label);
        System.out.println(" - point.y: " + y);
    }
}

void printIgnorePoint(LabeledPoint lp) {
    System.out.println("print ignore point");
    if (lp instanceof LabeledPoint(var p, var label)) {
        System.out.println(" - point.label: " + label);
    }
}

record Point(int x, int y) { }
record LabeledPoint(Point p, String label) { }
```

The output is:

```
print extract point
print ignore point
 - point.label: gamma
```

The method printExtractPoint does not enter the "if" clause. It also does not warn me that one of the elements is null. Obviously the pattern was not matched at all since the documentation says:

> The null value does not match any record pattern.

Yest still I would like to see some sort of warning which says which component is null. Can this be achieved in an elegant, concise way?

Comment: @xerx593 
the question is more about traversing the graph of components. I gave an example of simple nesting, only one level (LabeledPoint has nested Point class), but in reality the nesting levels can reach more deep. Anyhow your solution checks lp, which obviously is not null, please read the code again.

Comment: I don’t know of any syntactical construct in the Java programming language that produces warning messages, so I don’t understand why you expect such a feature here. If you want to know whether `p` is `null`, you have to implement a test, like for any other condition, i.e. `if (lp instanceof LabeledPoint(var p, var label) && p == null) …`. If this results in a large number of patterns due to your complex pattern with lots of nullable components, you may use a `switch` instead of `if`…

Answer (score 0):

Java 20 introduced null case statements. see https://youtu.be/aKaw9W789wU?t=666.

Basically:

```
switch (o)
{
    case null -> //handle null
    case <other-value> ->
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: how this apply to my question? Could you post the code? Please note that my question is more about situation when we are extracting nested pattern and one of the "children" is  null.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, as @Holger pointed out, if you have a complex construct you can use switch, but as far as I know, switch is the only Java component (to date) that has a null pattern built in. If, as in your case, you don't want to use switch, you can run an `Objects::notNull` on the variables you want to check (e.g. `Stream.of(<vars to check>).allMatch(Objects::notNull)` ) with the `instaceof` check in the if clause.